# FileProvider: No data when sending file

Tags: android

I've configured a FileProvider and I'm trying to send files but the external applications (Google Drive, etc) handling the intents throw an error saying that the intent contained no data. What am I missing here?

```
            File backupPath = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "backups");
            File backupFile = new File(backupPath, clickedBackup.getFilename());
            Uri contentUri = getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.test.app.fileprovider", backupFile);

            // create new Intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            // set flag to give temporary permission to external app to use your FileProvider
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.setDataAndType(
                    contentUri,
                    getContext().getContentResolver().getType(contentUri));
            // validate that the device can open your File!
            PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
            if (intent.resolveActivity(pm) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Logcat shows the following:

```
12-18 12:47:55.554  1698  2490 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SEND dat=content://com.test.app.fileprovider/backups/20171918_121910.bak typ=application/octet-stream flg=0x3000001 cmp=com.google.android.apps.docs/.shareitem.UploadMenuActivity} from uid 10079
```

The content URI looks good to me but for some reason it's not working. Any ideas?

Here is the provider paths.

```
<paths>
    <files-path name="backups" path="backups/" />
</paths>
```

And finally, the provider declaration.

```
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.test.app.fileprovider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/exposed_filepaths" />
        </provider>
```

UPDATE: logcat also shows the following which may or not be key to the problem here

```
12-18 13:21:23.739  4818  6764 E DataSourceHelper: Uploading single file but neither EXTRA_STREAM nor EXTRA_TEXT is specified.
12-18 13:21:23.790  1431  1483 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
12-18 13:21:23.796  1431  1483 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) HwBinder:1431_1 identical 1 line
12-18 13:21:23.807  1431  1483 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
12-18 13:21:23.824  4818  4818 E UploadMenuActivity: No files requested to be uploaded: android.intent.action.SEND
```

EDIT 2: Adding this makes it work just fine:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
```

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on? Do you see specific stack traces from these other apps in LogCat that you could add to your question (as they might offer clues)? Are you sure that file exists? Since `.bak` files will not have a standard MIME type, have you tried using `application/octet-stream`?

Comment: I am indeed using application/octet-stream as you see from the logcat output :) I can't see any stack traces from the Google Drive app in this case that leads me anywhere. Im testing this with the emulator running Android 8.0 and 8.1. I can also confirm that the file defined as backupFile in the code above exists.

Comment: I'd probably toss together a simple *separate* app that supported `ACTION_SEND` for `application/octet-stream`, then use that app to see what life is like on the client side of this communications. If that app can successfully open a stream and consume the bytes, then Google Drive and others should be able to do the same thing (though this is a key reason for having the `ACTION_SEND` test be a separate app, rather than just some activity within your own app).

Comment: Please check out my updated post. Does that last logcat output tell you anything? I wasnt aware I had to specify EXTRA_STREAM when sending files.

Comment: Ugh. It's too early in the morning for me to be trying to help on Stack Overflow -- I can't believe that I missed that. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47868623/115145).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, getContext().getContentResolver().getType(contentUri));
```

to:

```
intent.setType(contentUri, "application/octet-stream");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
```

`ACTION_SEND` uses `EXTRA_STREAM` — not the `Uri` facet of the `Intent` — for sending over the `Uri`. And since you know the MIME type, there is no sense in using IPC calls to derive it via `ContentResolver`.

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to set type which is missing. Try adding below:

```
intent.setType("image/*|application/pdf|audio/*");
```

for more details visit https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Comment: First, the code in the question is already setting the type, via `setDataAndType()`. Second, `setType()` does not support pipe-delimited MIME types.